# Sharing Internet between vlan(s)

Tags: router, switch

[image]

Assume that:

Router connect to FA0/1 port on the switch. This port is configured to be trunk port.

I also configure Router on Stick on the Router. And the router connect to modem

Port FA0/2-3 and FA0/3-4 on the switch are configured to vlan 10 and 20, respectively.

My question is, can the computers on both vlan(s) access the internet? If not, is there any solution for this?

P/s: I know that there are some similar questions. However, I would like to make the situation as simple as possible, as I am a novice networking leaner.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My question is, can the computers on both vlan(s) access the internet?

They should be able to, **if the router supports VLANs**. Because it's connected to a trunk port, it will be receiving *tagged* packets and needs to be configured to have virtual "VLAN interfaces", one for each VLAN ID that you want to route.

After this is done, each VLAN interface behaves like a separate Ethernet interface and the router only needs to perform standard routing. Anything that it can do with physical subnets, it can also do with VLANs.

Answer (score 0):

Your questions are non-sequiturs, so this question can't actually be answered based on only the information provided.

Switches and VLANS do not have anything to do with routing packets to the Internet or between VLANS - that is the job of the router (and specifying only the VLAN configuration tells us nothing about the routing)

If you think of a VLAN as creating a virtual switch it might be helpful.   In order to know if computers on both VLAN's can access the Internet it is necessary to know how the router is configured to handle traffic to and from each of the VLANS, including how IP address assignment/NAT'ing is being handled.